# Regex not displaying well whe using PHP preg_quote

Tags: php, regex, preg-quote

Hi Im trying to concatinate a string before converting that string into regex in PHP, but the problem is it's not displaying as expected. I've been searching using google and found out about [preg_quote](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php), problem is it's not working well.

Here is my example:

```
$mystring = "banana"; // put this to a variable assume this value is dynamic
$regex_str = "/^"$mystring"\-[a-z0-9]\-[a-z0-9]$/"; 
//Im expecting expecting /^banana\-[a-z0-9]\-[a-z0-9]$/
$regex = preg_quote($regex_str);
```

but what I am getting is:

```
/\^banana\\\-\[a\-z0\-9\]\\\-\[a\-z0\-9\]\$/
```

and always returning the wrong value.

Comment: `preg_quote()` is intended to be called on the string you're adding into the regex, not on the entire regex after the addition.

Comment: You quote `$mystring` and concatenate it with the rest of the regex. There is no meaning in quoting the whole regex.

Comment: Is that your actual code? You should be getting an error.

Comment: @Anonymous yeah I know right? that's why I'm asking on how to fix this. thanks

Comment: @loki9 No, I mean the code you show doesn't even produce an output besides the syntax error. The code you're actually using is likely different.

Comment: actually it wont display an syntax error because I just echoed it.

Comment: @loki9 Try testing exactly the code you used in the question. You should see a syntax error from PHP on the second line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call `preg_quote()` on the string you're adding before you add it into the regex:

```
$mystring = "banana";
$regex_str = "/^" . preg_quote($mystring, "/") . "\-[a-z0-9]\-[a-z0-9]$/";
```

Comment: @Jonny5 yes I also just found out. it worked for me tho, I'll just edit my question